# How do I detect STX over a TCP socket?

Tags: c++, tcp, ros

I have a server and a client communicating with each other over TCP.

On the client side, I'm trying to send an STX before sending some data. When I sniff the TCP packets on Wireshark, I do see the STX, and the data is getting sent too. So there is some problem with how I'm trying to reconstruct the message on the server side.

On the server side, I'm trying to read the STX like this:

```
while(ros::ok()) {
ss.str(std::string()); 
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255); //rcv Buffer
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
ss << buffer;
const char stx = '\x02';

std::string stxstr;
stxstr.push_back(stx);
std::string identifier;
std::stringstream::pos_type pos = ss.tellg();
ss>>identifier;

if(identifier == stxstr){
ROS_INFO("Found STX");
}
else {
ss.seekg(pos); 
}


n = write(newsockfd,"Recd",4); //ACK to client
if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");}
```

But I am not able to get the STX from the stringstream. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly related: `ss << buffer` will stop at the first NUL byte in `buffer`. You should probably use `ss.str(std::string(buffer, n))`.

Comment: What does your protocol look like? `ss >> identifier` will read the first "word" (the first block of non-whitespace characters after any whitespace characters at the start)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I went ahead with (memchr) and it works for me!